# Why does this .indexOf method not work on this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have the following code:

```
var newArr = [];

function mutation(arr) {

  //Makes both values lowercase

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    newArr.push(arr[i].toLowerCase());

  }

  //splits the letters of the second value into separate values.

  var letters = [];
  letters.push(newArr[1]);
  letters = letters.toString();
  letters = letters.split('');

  //checks to see if there is a letter that isn't in the first value.

  for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {

    if (newArr[1].indexOf(letters[j]) == -1) {

      return false;

    }

  }

  return true;

}

mutation(["voodoo", "no"]);
```

It works on something like (["hello", "hey"]), but it doesn't work on the method above. Why does the .indexOf method not work on this array?

Comment: Why is `newArr` a global variable when it doesn't need to be?

Comment: Why are you converting an array to a string? Why use an array in the first place? What's wrong, the code is doing exactly what it's told...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really know what the code should do but lets check it step by step:

```
var newArr = [];

function mutation(arr) {

  // Makes both values lowercase
  // arr is now ["voodoo", "no"]

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    newArr.push(arr[i].toLowerCase());

  }
  // newArr has the same content: ["voodoo", "no"]
  //splits the letters of the second value into separate values.

  var letters = [];
  letters.push(newArr[1]); // letters is now ["no"]
  letters = letters.toString(); // letters is now "no"
  letters = letters.split(''); // letters is now ["n", "o"]

  //checks to see if there is a letter that isn't in the first value.

  for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) { // foreach ["n", "o"]

    if (newArr[1].indexOf(letters[j]) == -1) { // "no".indexOf("n") and "no".indexOf("o") is always > -1 


      return false; // so false is never returned

    }

  }

  return true; // true is always returned

}

mutation(["voodoo", "no"]);
```

I think you should change the

```
if (newArr[1].indexOf(letters[j]) == -1)
```

to

```
if (newArr[0].indexOf(letters[j]) == -1)
```

if you want to test if one letter of the second word is not included in the first word.

Comment: I did that, but now (["hello"], ["hey"]) doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? If I change the index from 1 to 0 and call the function with ["hello", "hey"] as parameter I get false as return value.